# hide button on return of ajax value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The is a button on whose click certain task is performed through ajax. through ajax i get a result in json format that looks like this in console

```
 ["25", 16, "ABC", "DEF", 1]
```

Now i want that whenever there is `1` in 4th position i wish to hide few buttons. the code that i wrote is

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'script.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      txt: txtbox,
      hidden: hiddenTxt
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function(returndata) {

        if(returndata[4]=='1')
        {
            $("#first").hide();
            $("#second").hide();
            $("#third").hide();
        }

    },
    error: function() { 
      console.error('Failed to process ajax !');
    }

  });
```

the if condition seems to work because i tried to put an alert box within the if condition and it worked, however the buttons are still getting displayed.

the code i tried for test with alert box is

```
if (returndata[4] == 1) 
    {
        alert("1");
    }
```

Can anyone please tell why is this happening

Comment: `if(returndata[4]===1)`

Comment: Try removing the quotes from around the '1', as it looks like it is being returned as an integer, not a string: `returndata[4]===1` (also, use triple equals sign)

Comment: Maybe you need to do `returnData.data[4] === 1` ?

Comment: @JohnnyAW it didnt worked, stil able to see the buttons

Comment: @joe_young didnt work out, buttons still getting displayed

Comment: @aup showing syntax error

Comment: maybe you need to use JSON.parse(returndata) and then access it like a normal array of javascript?

Comment: `console.log(returndata)` - what is displayed in your JavaScript console when you add this as the first line in your `success` function?

Comment: @James Donnelly the reply that i get is ["25", 16, "ABC", "DEF", 1]

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: @st001 What's `typeof returndata` then?

Comment: @V P no error in console

Comment: What the cr@p? How can that be a number? Shouldn't it be an object? Then something is wrong from the server!

Comment: number? finally, what this says? <code>console.log(returndata[4])</code>

Comment: @V P i guess i didn't put forward my query properly, therefore have updated my post. in case u need to know anything else regarding the que then plz let me know, and would appreciate if you could help me find a sol for it

Comment: @Praveen Kumar I apologize for not putting forward my question in a proper manner, have updated my post, would have appreciated if u culd have helped me but thanks for going through my post

Comment: @st001 Can you try to simplify the code by eliminating unnecessary stuff? I am answering for this.

Comment: And yes, in the mean time you have already got 4 upvotes and one from me too! `:)`

Comment: @JohnnyAW in javascript the == does not distinguish the number value 1 from the string value "1". Neither does it distinguish null from unidentified from the number 0 and the string value "0"

Comment: Am also eager to know the ans... :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is what you have done. I am in a challenge to solve your issue. Let's do one by one. First attempt, try this instead of your code:

```
$.post("script.php", {txt: txtbox, hidden: hiddenTxt}, function (res) {
  alert("Response: " + res);
  alert("Type: " + typeof res);
});
```

Please let me know your results in the comments. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You have matched one '1' as a `string` in your hide section, but in the alert section matched one 1 as `number`. This may be the problem.

**Avoid this**

```
if(returndata[4]=='1')
```

**Use this**

```
if(returndata[4] == 1)
```

Comment: Please go through the comments.

Comment: @prem. This not the problem. In javascript '1' & 1 will both equal true if return data for is 1 or '1'. We're not comparing with type equality - https://jsfiddle.net/yf6Lud24/

Answer (score 0):

try follow changes in your ajax method...

1. use GET method instead of POST
2. no need to use dataType:'json'

   ```
   $.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: 'script.php',
   data: {
     txt: txtbox,
     hidden: hiddenTxt
   },
   cache: false,
   success: function(returndata) {

       if(returndata[4]=='1')
       {
           $("#first").hide();
           $("#second").hide();
           $("#third").hide();
       }

   },
   error: function() { 
     console.error('Failed to process ajax !');
   }
     });
   ```

regards
prem

Answer (score 0):

In comments I see thatYou have posted ajax result which is:

```
["25", 16, "ABC", "DEF", 1]
```

Your problem is comparission which is **==="1"**( I saw that type of comparison in question when I started writing this answer ) and You have 1 as number not "1" as string, **===** means type comparission, so in correct way it gives false because 1 is numbet and "1" is string. You can fix this by changing condition to:

```
returndata[4]===1
```

or without type check:

```
returndata[4]==1
```

That's it.

To more understand this answer I have prepared few examples.

```js
console.log("1 === '1'");
console.log(1==='1');

console.log("1 === 1");
console.log(1===1);


console.log("1 == '1' ( no type comarision )");
console.log(1=='1');
```